# How to display subcategory list in static blocks of Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php

I am making static block and listing products like this

```
{{block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml"}}
```

**but i want to display subcategory in my static block for magento 2.**

Answer (score 1):

A widget would be your best bet. There are a number of custom widget examples that allow you to display a list of sub-categories.  Try this one out:
https://github.com/emizentech/magento2-category-list-widget